# How to properly read and write a file using Windows.Storage on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I'm needing to just simply write to a file and read from a file in Windows Phone 8 using the Windows.Storage APIs. This is relatively easy using the old IsolatedStorage method, but it's proving significantly harder using the new WinRT API.

I've been trying to write it, but there seem to be all these weird things like IBuffer. and such. Using the full version of WinRT, it's quite easy using Windows.Storage.FileIO which appears to exist to keep developers like me from going insane. However, it's not implemented in the Phone version. Also, I watched a [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-04-Files-and-Storage-on-Windows-Phone-8) video which showed some code samples, but they had a mistake in that they used methods marked Security Critical to get regular streams. Apparently getting a regular Stream just isn't allowed.

So, can someone provide me with a concise and correct snippet on how to just read a file into a string and how to write a string to a file, complete with proper using and disposal techniques?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, take a look at [Akavache](https://github.com/github/Akavache). You can either use it if it solves your problem, or take a look around the source to see how they worked around these issues.

Comment: @vcsjones good thing to keep in mind, but we can't include any dependencies :( Also, it uses IsolatedStorage on WP8

Comment: The [PCL Storage](http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) project provides a common interface for I/O operations with portable class libraries. Perhaps this could give you some hints?

Comment: Is there a reason `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(strFileLoc)))...` style code doesn't work for you? I've got an [app deployed on my dev registered WP8](http://catchingmono.blogspot.com/2014/09/easy-text-files-on-windows-phone.html) where standard file writing seems to work fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
public async Task WriteDataToFileAsync(string fileName, string content)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);

    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}

public async Task<string> ReadFileContentsAsync(string fileName)
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    try
    {
        var file = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(fileName);

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

use them like this:

```
await this.WriteDataToFileAsync("afile.txt", "some text to save in a file");

var contents = await this.ReadFileContentsAsync("afile.txt");
```

Comment: A couple of issues: 1. You should return Task on the write method, so it will be awaitable. 2. Looks like you're writing UTF8 and reading back UTF16, or is the StreamReader clever enough to tell the Encoding without being told?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts good spots. Will teach me to just copy and paste from random internet sources ;)

Comment: Also, using `OpenStreamForReadAsync` is SECURITY CRITICAL

Comment: @Earlz May I ask why it is important that `OpenStreamForReadAsync` is Security Critical? Microsoft is using that in there sample code ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx) so it seems we are supposed to use these.

Comment: @StefanWexel yea, it ended up not mattering. I don't understand what Security Critical even means now, but I didn't get any certification errors calling security critical functions from non-security critical code.. so I guess it's all good

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried that with Windows Phone 8, but [here's](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c5#WinRTXamlToolkit/IO/Extensions/StringIOExtensions.cs) what WinRT XAML Toolkit has for Windows 8 that could work.

﻿

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace WinRTXamlToolkit.IO.Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extensions for simple writing and reading of strings to/from files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Note that these were created before FileIO class existed in WinRT, but they still serve a purpose.
    /// </remarks>
    public static class StringIOExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a string from a text file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
        /// <param name="folder">The folder.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task<string> ReadFromFile(
            string fileName,
            StorageFolder folder = null)
        {
            folder = folder ?? ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

            using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                using (var inStream = fs.GetInputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    using (var reader = new DataReader(inStream))
                    {
                        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fs.Size);
                        string data = reader.ReadString((uint)fs.Size);
                        reader.DetachStream();

                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes a string to a text file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The text to write.</param>
        /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
        /// <param name="folder">The folder.</param>
        /// <param name="options">
        /// The enum value that determines how responds if the fileName is the same
        /// as the name of an existing file in the current folder. Defaults to ReplaceExisting.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task WriteToFile(
            this string text,
            string fileName,
            StorageFolder folder = null,
            CreationCollisionOption options = CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
        {
            folder = folder ?? ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(
                fileName,
                options);
            using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outStream))
                    {
                        if (text != null)
                            dataWriter.WriteString(text);

                        await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                        dataWriter.DetachStream();
                    }

                    await outStream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked better than the "simple example". Probably because this code cleans up with methods like FlushAsync. I'm using VS2013 update 2, and things change a lot in this area!