# Saving exceptions to report them on the next start

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

If an error occurs while my app is running I'm saving the Stacktrace in a file.

```
internal static void ReportException(Exception ex, string extra)
{
    try
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            SafeDeleteFile(store);
            TextWriter output = new StreamWriter(store.CreateFile(filename));
            output.WriteLine(extra);
            output.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            output.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            output.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exf)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error occured while reporting an Error");
    }
}
```

On the next start up I want to read from this file, but it seems like the file didn't get saved.

```
internal static void CheckForPreviousException()
{
    try
    {
        string contents = null;
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (store.FileExists(filename))
            {
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)))
                {
                    contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                SafeDeleteFile(store);
            }
        }
        if (contents != null)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("A problem occurred the last time you ran this application. Would you like to send an email to report it?", "Problem Report", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                // Sending an Email if the user wants to
                EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
                email.To = mail;
                email.Subject = subject;
                email.Body = contents;
                SafeDeleteFile(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
                email.Show();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception){}

    finally
    {
        SafeDeleteFile(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
    }
}

private static void SafeDeleteFile(IsolatedStorageFile store)
{
    try
    {
        store.DeleteFile(filename);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: When you try this the file was not created or it content was empty?

Comment: store.FileExists(filename) returns false

Comment: Here's another question on SO that regards writing/reading files in WP8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623189/how-to-properly-read-and-write-a-file-using-windows-storage-on-windows-phone-8. Althoug the approach is different, it might get you to find a solution.

Comment: That didn't actually help, because the windows phone seems like not to store my file. On the next startup however the file doesn't exist.
Could it be that the emulator is causing this "error"?

Comment: Next startup means , are you closing the emulator and restarting it again and checking?When you close the emulator isolated storage memory will be erased..

Comment: No, i throw an exception to simulate a crash and start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Since WP8 you can go back to the home screen, simply by using the back button.
From there, you can navigate to your app in the applist 
(if you use one of the standard templates, it has a star icon)

Check if the file pops up now by navigating to you app again.

As suggested restarting the emulator can indeed be the source of your problem.

Comment: This is what i do, and my file doesn't exist then anymore. but why?