# How to write text to a file in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I found this example of how to write data to a file in Windows Phone 8:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625701/181771

> ```
> public async Task WriteDataToFileAsync(string fileName, string content) {
> byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
>
> var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
> var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
>
> using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
> {
>     await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
> } }
> ```

This works, but the text is encoded. I'm attempting to write a JSON file so I'd like to save the raw text.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: take a look over here for the sample from msdn.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use `StreamWriter` that will automatically deal with the encoding.

```
public async Task WriteDataToFileAsync(string fileName, string content)
{
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(s))
    {
        await writer.WriteAsync(content);
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)
it is pretty simple serialize with this

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small"
//  ]
//}
```

Then save the string named json to file.

You will find more helpful stuff here http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html