# How can I create a simple text file on a windows phone (8.1) that can be accessed trough USB cable?

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

So as title states, I would like to create a simple text file, that I could write to from my C# application, and copy it to my PC trough an USB cable.

Just to be clear, I would like to write a file to this place, because I can access this from my PC.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a capability for writing to the Documents folder on the phone, but adding it to your manifest would cause your app to fail the certification process in the Windows Phone Store.

The capability is called `documentsLibrary`

```
<Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
```

If you declare it, you can then read and write files in `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`.

Comment: I had to also add file associations the way described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211438.aspx), it works now, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have access to the public - documents folder from the windwsphone. Look at the following code-snippet (details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625701/2653134)

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, however this snippet (and your link too) is about local storage, which is not accessible from PC.